# Are there any example pre-built Kingdoms anywhere?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, realm-management

I'm intending to use the [Pathfinder Kingdom rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCampaign/kingdomsAndWar/kingdomBuilding.html) to simulate running a empire in an entirely different system (Rolemaster). What I'd like is some example Kingdoms and cities that are already established to save myself some work so I can just modify them instead of having to build them from scratch.

Are there any example pre-built kingdoms and cities for the Kingdom rules anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

I did run into a RaleighDND's [PF example kingdom sheet](https://stormgaard.obsidianportal.com/wikis/kingdom-building-guide-sheet) on obsidian portal.

There's an [Open Office Spreadsheet](http://www.pathfinderdb.com/gamemaster-tools/game-aids/1187-open-office-kingmaker-kingdom-record-sheet) for helping you manage the whole process. That might ease your burden a bit. Just whip something up and convert what ever you need to convert.

---

Although an alternative might be ACKS (Adventurer Conqueror King).
There are some pretty crunchy rules for Kingdom and Nation building in the core book. Honestly they seem like the most straight-forward rules I've come across for allowing players to own, and interact with, cities/territories/etc.

Also, ACKS is an Old School clone so it might segue to Rolemaster better than Pathfinder.

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not answer the question posed.

Comment: I suggest editing your post with the last two points first as they more directly address the topic.  And then preface what is currently your first paragraph with why you want to point them at ACKS (because it might work better with Rolemaster).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you, but that's not a prebuilt kingdom :)